# Objective C making a calculator with hidden numbers

Tags: objective-c, xcode, calculator

I am new here and just started learning about Objective C.
I am having problem in making a calculator with codes. 
For example, i want to set some codes e.g. A=55, B=42, C=19.....to Z= 66
Then allow user to type in any letter in the textfield and calculate the final sum of value.

My question is how can i set these codes (A-Z) then my calculation method can run user entered letters?

```
        result.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i",????? ];
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific what your want to do. And what exactly your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes in my mind is to save those values in a `int[]` and to retrieve them when you need. Of course it can be annoying to store all the values, especially if they don't have a mathematical order.
To get those values you may simply do something like

```
result.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i",codes[letter-'A']];
```

where `codes` is the `int[]` where you stored your values and `letter` is the chose letter

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get the code for that, here is the code i have now. Sequence is the textfield that user enter. -(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender{
    int code  = ([sequence.text intValue]);

    int A=1;
    int B=1;
    int C=1;
    int D=1;
    
    
            result.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", code=4*(A+C)+2*(B+D) ];

Comment: The output windows showed the following, Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TMcalc calculate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68bb640'. It seems that i cannot recognize the input letters. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that TMcalc has a method called calculate? It seems you are calling a method that does not exists...May you post some code?

Comment: Here is the .h file.    interface TMcalc : UIViewController{
    UISegmentedControl *segmentcontrol1;
    UITextField* Forward;
   IBOutlet UITextField* sequence;
    IBOutlet UILabel*result;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentcontrol1;

- (IBAction)calculate;
- (IBAction) clear;
-(IBAction) goKeyboard:(id) sender;
-(IBAction) tapbackground: (id) sender;
-(IBAction) goback:(id) sender;
-(IBAction) segmentedControlIndexCanged1;
@end

Comment: This is part of the .m file.  implementation TMcalc
@synthesize segmentcontrol1;

-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender{
    int code  = ([sequence.text integerValue]);

    int A=1;
    int B=1;
    int C=1;
    int D=1;
    
    
            result.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", code=(4*(A+C)) ];
    
}

Comment: in .h you defined `-(IBAction)calculate;` while in your .m you implemented `-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender;`. Try removing the parameter from your implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I was so careless. Now the other problem is that e.g. i type in AAACCC in the textfield, but it does not calculate as i want. code=(4*(A+C)) this equation. Is there another things i need to set before int A=something? Thanks

Comment: If i int A=1, C=1, then it will always run the equation of 4*(1+1) without looking at what the user input. May I know how can i solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Well it depends on what you want to do...What operation would you like to perform? how the result should depend on `code`?

Comment: I am not sure about the technical terms. What i want to do is allow user to enter random letters e.g. "ABCDABDBAB" random length as well. On my equation, i first set int A=1, int B=7, then equation set as 4*(total number of A + total number of B). Finally this calculator will give a integer number. How can this be done? thanks

Comment: Well, you should use a different approach to do that: first you need to parse the string, get the number of occurrences of each letter, then you can calculate the result as `4*(n_A*A+n_B*B...)`.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying, but don't know how to define the n = total number of A in the text. And I don't understand "parse the string" how can i do that?